# Why is addClass and removeClass breaking my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Before adding the 2 lines of code above, the whole function worked. Now only those two lines work when I click and the rest of my code doesn't. If I remove these two lines, the code works again. What could removing a class and adding a class possibly do to ruin the rest of this function? What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var subject;
    $('.subject').mouseenter(function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass(subject) ) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    });
    $('.subject').mouseleave(function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass(subject) ) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
            $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
        }
    });

    // BELOW IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

    $('[class$=-link]').click(function(){
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); // Why do these lines break the 
        $(this).addClass('selected');           // rest of this function?
        $('.' + subject).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $('.' + subject).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
        subject = $(this).attr('class').replace("-link","");
        $('.'+ subject ).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4SUX/2/

Comment: Which exact line breaks it? Do you know what $(this) is in this context?

Comment: Aha! It seems the `$(this).addClass('selected');` is what breaks the code. Does it have something to do with `this`?

Comment: @Syon the mouseenter and mouseleave are bound to `.subject` the classes removed and added are `.selected` . how can that break? I would rather say that there indeed is a problem with `this` in the selector. @Brett: What is selected by the `[class$=-link]` selector?

Comment: I'm confused because the addClass is fpr the class-link, and the mouseenter and mouseleave is to something with a completely different class. :o

Comment: can you post your (partial) html that shows at least the clickable links?

Comment: @barts Oops, I must have read that wrong. That's what I get for skimming.

Comment: that is a rather weird selector for the click handler, what does it do ? var subject never gets assigned (unless its been snipped from your post)

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4SUX/
Hope this helps!
And sorry, i clicked tidy up on jsfiddle and it ruined my beautifully tabbed html lol
@NimChimpsky subject gets assigned at almost the very end.

Comment: I updated fiddle for tabbed html to help the debugging process. http://jsfiddle.net/n4SUX/2/

Comment: `$(this).addClass('selected');`, then `subject = $(this).attr('class').replace("-link","");`. Think about it!

Comment: I removed my answer, as I only see now there's more in the fiddle outside of my visible window. I will bang my head to the wall myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want something like this (avoiding the need to change the HTML) :

```
$('[class$=-link]').click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('.' + subject).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0).end().find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    subject = $(this).attr('class').replace("-link","");//execute this line while "selected" class is not present
    $('.'+ subject).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $(this).addClass('selected');//add after everything else is complete
});
```